# Delphi - Create form behind another form

Tags: delphi, forms, z-order

I'm using Delphi 4.
I have a main form with a button that dynamically creates a new form.
I'd like the new form to be visible, but to show up BEHIND the main form.

I've tried calling `SendToBack()` immediately after `FormCreate()`. But that makes the window flicker quickly before it's actually sent to back.

I've tried making the form invisible, then `SendToBack()`, then `Visible := true`.
But the new form is still at the front.

It looks like `SendToBack()` only works with visible forms? How can I cause the form to be shown behind the main form?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
SetWindowPos(newform.Handle, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW
  or SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOOWNERZORDER or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOACTIVATE);

newform.Visible := true;
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

make the second window (e.g. form2) invisible, then call:

```
showWindow(form2.handle,SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work.
if I call ShowWindow(newform.handle, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE), then newform.Visible := true. It still comes out in front.

Comment: why call newform.visible :=true; ? if you leave that out, it should work.

Comment: Later on, i check "if(newform.visible) then do-stuff;". But using the showWindow() without the visible:=true, the visible property seems to be false.